# Is it possible to grant permission for create resource group to service principal if no subscriptions are available?

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-sdk-.net, azure-rbac

I try to grant permission for create resource group to service principal in my UWP C# project. I use Azure SDK for .NET to create confidential application registration and acquire access token. It is worked with my extension methods, to prevent platform check. But when I try to get role assignments for service principal, I receive Azure.RequestFailedException 0x80131500, "The subscription 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' could not be found".

```c#
ResourceIdentifier scope = new ResourceIdentifier($"/subscriptions/{MyTenantId}");
ConfidentialClientCredential credential = new ConfidentialClientCredential(MyConfidentialClientApplication);
ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(credential);
RoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignmentCollection = AuthorizationExtensions.GetRoleAssignments(armClient, scope);
IEnumerable<RoleAssignmentResource> roleAssignments = roleAssignmentCollection?.GetAll($"$filter=atScope()+and+assignedTo('{strServicePrincipalId}')");
if(roleAssignments != null)
{
    AuthorizationRoleDefinitionResource roleDefinition = null;
    foreach(RoleAssignmentResource curRoleAssignment in roleAssignments)    // <-- exception throws there
    {
        if(curRoleAssignment?.HasData == true && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(curRoleAssignment.Data.RoleDefinitionId?.Name))
        {
            roleDefinition = await AuthorizationExtensions.GetAuthorizationRoleDefinitionAsync(armClient, scope, curRoleAssignment.Data.RoleDefinitionId);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using my tenant ID here as my subscription ID because it was returned by the Azure CLI command:

```sh
az account show --query "id"
```

I guess that AAD RBAC can be used for this purpose, but I haven't found suitable AD permission.
Is there any way to grant permission for create resource group in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that, ***subscription ID*** is different from *tenant ID*. If you
> don't have subscription, you can **neither** create resource group
> **nor** assign RBAC role to service principal.

If there are **no** subscriptions, you will get **tenant ID** in response when you run `az account show --query "id"` command.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via CLI and got below results:***

When I ran below commands, I got **tenant ID** in my response as I don't have subscriptions like below:

```
az login --allow-no-subscriptions --only-show-errors
az account show --query "id"
```

**Response:**

[image]

I have one service principal in my tenant like below:

[image]

When I tried to **assign role** to the above *service principal* using below CLI command by giving **`tenantID`** as subscriptionID, I got **same error** as you like this:

```
az role assignment create --assignee-object-id <sp_objectID> --assignee-principal-type ServicePrincipal --role Contributor --scope /subscriptions/<tenant ID>
```

**Response:**

[image]

Without subscription, you can ***only*** perform **directory-level** operations like managing **Azure AD** users, groups, app registration etc...

You definitely need subscription to manage **Azure resources** like resource groups, virtual machines, storage accounts, role assignments etc...

To **resolve** the error, make sure to have at least **one subscription** linked to your tenant and login again like below:

```
az login --allow-no-subscriptions --only-show-errors
az account show --query "id"
```

[image]

When I ran the below **CLI command** again by including above **`subscriptionID`**, role assignment created successfully like below:

```
 az role assignment create --assignee-object-id <sp_objectID> --assignee-principal-type ServicePrincipal --role Contributor --scope /subscriptions/<subscription ID>
```

**Response:**

[image]